# How to write multiple times in external console application using java?

Tags: java, process, outputstream

I need to dialogue with an external c++ console program (read output and write input). I read from the application with a Thread (and it works), but when it needs input, it works only the first time, then the stream probably remains empty, and it doesn't receive the second input (and external program closes).

The application i'm using is a simple .exe wrote in c++ that:

1. print "Insert first input"
2. scan input1
3. print input1
4. print "Insert second input"
5. scan input2
6. print input2

Main class:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ExampleCom {

    public static Communication com = new Communication();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;

        com.read();
        while(true)
        {
            s = in.nextLine();
            com.write(s);
        }
    }
```

Communication class:

```
    public class Communication
    {
        Process p;
        OutputStream writer;
        public InputStream reader = null;
        Read r; //Class that with a loop read all exe input

        Communication()
        {   
            try{
                p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("C:\\esempio.exe");
                writer = p.getOutputStream();
                reader = p.getInputStream();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }

        public void read()
        {
            r = new Read();
            Thread threadRead = new Thread(r);
            threadRead.start();
        }

        public void write(String s)
        {
            try{
                writer.write(s.getBytes());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
```

How can I send my string (like "writer.write('hello')") when the external application needs it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `write()` method, you have the line

```
            writer.close();
```

which means that after calling it the first time, you are closing the input stream to your C++. As far as it is concerned, it sees the "end of file" marker after your first input.

What you should do is put the `close()` in a separate method, and call that method only when you are done working with that process.

Now, as your target program expects text input and will only interpret the input if it gets an end-of-line (as per your answer to the question in my comment), you should supply that end-of-line to it.

Instead of doing raw byte-writes, I think a better approach would be to use a `PrintWriter` for that output stream, and use as naturally as you use `System.out.println()`. It can also save you on the `flush()` part.

You are interpreting it incorrectly when you see that your program is not reading the input until you `close()`. It's not waiting - it sends it as soon as you call `flush()`. But the C++ waits for either an end-of-file or an end-of-line, and since you are not giving it an end-of-line, then only `close()`, that sends it end-of-file, causes it to accept the input. But then you can no longer send any further data.

So the solution is, first, to define your `writer` as a `PrintWriter`. Instead of

```
OutputStream writer;
```

Use

```
PrintWriter writer;
```

And instead of

```
            writer = p.getOutputStream();
```

Use

```
            writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(), true);
```

The `true` there will give you auto-flush whenever you use the `println()` command.

Now, your write method should be:

```
    public void write(String s)
    {
        writer.println(s);
    }
```

Note that a `PrintWriter` doesn't produce exceptions, so if you care about errors, you have to check for them using `checkError()`.

And of course, have the `close()` in a separate method, as I mentioned before.

Comment: Does your C++ program expect the input to be text, and does it try to read it line by line?

Comment: I tryed to make a close() method, but if I use only "write()" and "flush()" methods, it does a "string append" without sending it to the external process.

Comment: I asked you about the C++ program. Does it expect its input to be text? Does it read it usually line by line (that is, expecting that you press return at the end of your input?).

Comment: Yes, my C++ program expects input line by line, everytime the function "write()" is called (e.g. not "Hello + world" but "Hello" and "world")

Comment: Sorry but sooner I didn't see your comment. Yes, it expect that I press return

Answer (score 0):

Because the `write()` method might throw an IOException, it is advisable to call the `close()` method inside a finally block.Place the `writer.close()` method outside the try clause:

```
finally {
if(writer != null) {
    writer.close();
}
```